# Question re: CSS and HTML for creating child containers in Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to follow along with Ben Frain *Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3 - Second Edition* chapter 3 where he discusses flexbox use. At the end of the [chapter we end up with (on jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/rverne/dk7302gx/) an example that looks swell until I add some more HTML containers as simple as a paragraph and a header. [See what happens here.](https://jsfiddle.net/rverne/dk7302gx/5/)

So another set of boxes is created in the columnar format. I wanted the h1 heading at the top of the box of course. I realize that the h1 container will have to coded in CSS but I've looked high and low for hours and have not been able to find a solution.  My concern is:
the training I've found on Flexbox is not addressing the way in which the protocol mandates another child be created when new HTML containers are added to the boxes. Please run any examples for solutions, with the code provided at jsfiddle, to verify it works.

Thanks much,

---

Here's the code

Ray

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #ebebeb;}

.FlexWrapper {
    background-color: indigo;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.FlexItems {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 6.25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.FlexHeader {
    background-color: #105B63;
    order: 1;
}

.FlexContent {
    background-color: #FFFAD5;
    order: 2;
    color: blue;
}

.FlexSideOne {
    background-color: #FFD34E;
    order: 3;
    color: crimson;
}

.FlexSideTwo {
    background-color: #DB9E36;
    order: 4;
    color: black;
}

.FlexFooter {
    background-color: #BD4932;
    order: 5;
}

@media (min-width: 30rem) {
    .FlexWrapper {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .FlexHeader {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .FlexContent {
        flex: 1;
        order: 3;
    }
    .FlexSideOne {
        width: 150px;
        order: 2;
    }
    .FlexSideTwo {
        width: 150px;
        order: 4;
    }
    .FlexFooter {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
© 2021 GitHub, Inc.
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Layout example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="FlexWrapper">
        <div class="FlexItems FlexContent"><h1>I am content in the Content.</h1><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexSideOne">I am content in the SideOne.
            
        </div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexSideTwo">I am content in the SideTwo.</div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexHeader">I am content in the Header.</div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexFooter">I am content in the Footer.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you're asking... it's because by default, the `flex-wrap` value is `no-wrap`. Set it to `wrap` on the flex container/parent `.FlexItems`.

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

This will allow the elements to wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column` to the `FlexContent` CSS selector. This will set the div to flex and make its flex direction vertical in orientation, stacking the `h1` on top of the `p` tags content.

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #ebebeb;}

.FlexWrapper {
    background-color: indigo;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.FlexItems {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 6.25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.FlexHeader {
    background-color: #105B63;
    order: 1;
}

.FlexContent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #FFFAD5;
    order: 2;
    color: blue;
}

.FlexSideOne {
    background-color: #FFD34E;
    order: 3;
    color: crimson;
}

.FlexSideTwo {
    background-color: #DB9E36;
    order: 4;
    color: black;
}

.FlexFooter {
    background-color: #BD4932;
    order: 5;
}

@media (min-width: 30rem) {
    .FlexWrapper {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .FlexHeader {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .FlexContent {
        flex: 1;
        order: 3;
    }
    .FlexSideOne {
        width: 150px;
        order: 2;
    }
    .FlexSideTwo {
        width: 150px;
        order: 4;
    }
    .FlexFooter {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
© 2021 GitHub, Inc.
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Layout example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="FlexWrapper">
        <div class="FlexItems FlexContent"><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexSideOne">I am content in the SideOne.
            
        </div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexSideTwo">I am content in the SideTwo.</div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexHeader"><h1>I am content in the Header.</h1></div>
        <div class="FlexItems FlexFooter">I am content in the Footer.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```